# What is the meaning of medical personalization in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **medical personalization** in this sentence?

> AI is driving the adoption and implementation of precision medicine:
>   an emerging approach for disease treatment and prevention that takes
>   into account individual variability in genes, environment, and
>   lifestyle for each person. Think of it as a type of **medical
>   personalization**. For example, around 25,000 people in the US are
>   diagnosed with brain tumors every year. Traditionally, they might all
>   be given the same course of treatment to see what might work in a
>   one-size-fits-all approach. Precision medicine will allow doctors and
>   researchers to predict more accurately which treatment and prevention
>   strategies for a particular disease will work in which groups of
>   people.

Here is the link below from this paragraph is taken

> https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2017/05/artificial-intelligence-will-change-the-world-heres-how

/

Comment: I put the term in your quotation in bold text so it was easier to locate.

Comment: It is very clearly explained, so I don't understand this question.

Comment: 'Targeted prevention' and 'personalized treatment' would be better terms, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Medical personalization means that the same disease is treated differently in different persons or group of persons, according to their personal characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

**personalization** is the noun form (*-ation*; inform*ation*, declar*ation*) of the verb **personalize**. **personalize** itself is a constructed verb (*-ize*; standard*ize*, minim*ize*) of the noun **[person](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20person&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR)**, where person stands for:

> person (n): *a human being regarded as an individual.*

**personalization** itself is a [more common term in recent years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=personalization&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpersonalization%3B%2Cc0) perhaps due to the proliferation of software and the ability of users to *personalize* their settings. **Personalization** is defined as:

> personalization (n): *the action of designing or producing something to meet someone's individual requirements.*

**Medical personalization** is the act of personalization, then, in a medical context. The text you provided goes on to clarify what this means:

> *"Traditionally, they might all be given the same course of treatment to see what might work in a one-size-fits-all approach. Precision medicine* [i.e.: medical personalization] *will allow doctors and researchers to predict more accurately which treatment and prevention strategies for a particular disease will work in which groups of people."*

Answer (score 1):

From  [National Cancer Institute](https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/treatment/types/precision-medicine)

> **Precision medicine** is an approach to patient care that allows doctors to select treatments that are most likely to help patients
>   based on a genetic understanding of their disease. This may also be
>   called **personalized medicine**.

Examples:

- using your genetics to fight a disease
- using the genetics of the disease or tumor to target it
- Using a neutered virus with a genetically designed payload to target
  a disease, a tumor or to target your immune cells vitalize them